# How to write the Sorting on a Singly Linked List in C

Tags: c

I have a question. I hope everybody help me.
I'm learning Data Structures in C. I have a homework but I can't find a solution to solve it.My teacher wants me write 11 sorts.
In singly linked list i has installed 6 sorts:Interchange Sort, Bubble Sort, Selection Sort, Quick Sort, Merge Sort and Radix Sort.
So i need everybody help me write 5 sorts: Insertion Sort, Binary Insertion Sort, Shaker Sort, Heap Sort, Shell Sort. If it can't use in singly linked list,can you tell me why it can't use? 
I really need your help. Please answer to help me.Thank you very very very much!!!!!

Comment: Wut?  This place isn't homework help, show us what you've written and we can help you find problems but there needs to be some sort of body of work.  I'm betting your school has a CS help center, and I would assume you wouldn't go to them and say "write this for me" so please don't expect us to.

Comment: Haha!!! This is not a freelance coding hub to help you cheat on your homework. See if your school has some tutors or a help center if you honestly need help.

Comment: As mentioned this is not a "freelance coding hub". This is a Questions & Answers website. If you have a specific question about some programming related stuff you can explain what you don't understand and what exactly do you need help with (_even without a body of work_), if the question is legit and clear enough that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

This will give you various sorting algorithms, and when you select most of the algorithms wikipedia will have some pseudo code for that algorithm.  It's a really good exercise to translate pseudo code into the native language that you're writing it in (in this case C); I still do it when I'm learning a new language since implementing sorting algorithms usually gives you a good handle on the basics of that language.

From a more mothering/lecturing point, you won't have an easier time in your later classes if all you end up doing is getting your code from other people, you need to solve it yourself, plain and simple.

From the list of one's you have done quick and merge sort are probably the hardest, if you have those written (and actually wrote them) the rest should be fairly easy.

Comment: I don't have a ideal to write it because i tried but it didn't success. I wrote sorting in array but i can't cover to singly linked list. I'm sorry because i write "write it for me". I am not good at English. I just want to help me find way to solve it. :(.Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @user2957264 same thing applies, code is code, it's the same across all languages, and not getting it on your first try doesn't mean give up and ask people to essentially write it for you (that's what it's being percieved as here) you have no code to present so there's nothing we at this board can do to help.  If you would create a question with "I've written this sorting algorithm and it isn't working, what am I doing wrong" that would be more appropriate.

Comment: I just want to know a idea to write it. I think about it more than 2 days and write it many times but i cant find problem to fix. I will learn more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2957264 good luck, and come back here when you've got some code written up, people here are much more friendly then =D

Comment: Yup, i will try. Because this is a first time i post question here, i can't clearly express my question. :D. Sorry about this. :)